# Can not get my Php script to work with my clickatell API

Tags: php, api, sms, clickatell

Below is my code. It is supposed to send an SMS message after your enter your phone number in to the field form on http://www.localsadvise.com/services-view/dolphin-cruises/ It is not sending the message.

The URL has to be http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg? followed by the variables listed below in the code. I am trying to use the Php script to send the sms rather than having to direct the browser to the clickatell website for HTTP access. If that makes any sense.

```
// The original link that worked using a simple META Refresh after form submit 
// http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=amdoch&password=OVUbMIXCZUeMIg&api_id=3536796&MO=1&from=19044383575&to=1". $phone . "&text=Dolphin%20Cruise%20Test%20Text

$user = "amdoch";
$password = "MYPASSWORDHERE";
$api_id = "MYAPIID";
$baseurl ="http://api.clickatell.com";
$text = urlencode("This is an example message");
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$from = "19044383575";
$to = $phone;

// auth call
$url = "$baseurl/http/auth?user=$user&password=$password&api_id=$api_id";

// do auth call
$ret = file($url);

// explode our response. return string is on first line of the data returned
$sess = explode(":",$ret[0]);
if ($sess[0] == "OK") {

    $sess_id = trim($sess[1]); // remove any whitespace
    $url = "$baseurl/http/sendmsg?session_id=$sess_id&MO=1&from=$from&to=$to&text=$text";

    // do sendmsg call
    $ret = file($url);
    $send = explode(":",$ret[0]);

    if ($send[0] == "ID") {
        echo "successnmessage ID: ". $send[1];
    } else {
        echo "<META http-equiv=refresh content=0;URL=http://www.localsadvise.com>send message failed";
    }
} else {
    echo "Authentication failure: ". $ret[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The file() function that you are using will not direct to the Clickatell website (just like  file_get_contents() or curl functions).

You are probably seeing the Clickatell system's API response because you have this in your script:

echo "successnmessage ID: ". $send[1];

Just remove that line....

Comment: I'll give it a try. You have experience with clickatell? I've tried to get support from them with no luck. I actually found this script on the clickatell website.

Comment: Nope that didn't work. Still failing to send the message. I'm thinking the issue is in the URL somewhere. I am using an HTTP API with clickatell. It's terrible that they offer no support of any kind for developers.

Comment: Just so you have an idea of what I am trying to accomplish. I want to send the sms and then have the end user redirected back to my website. I don't really want any outside linking if possible. Thus the Php script. Clickatell told me to use HTTP callback function which I have no clue about. Also everything that I've read about HTTP callback makes it appear that this is not what I really want for my situation.

Comment: Ok - your first described problem was about redirecting - is that solved? 

Regarding your new problem: if your messages are failing, tell us what the response from the server was (perhaps log it to file)...

Comment: You might also want to remove your password from your example.

Comment: Another note - in the first lines of your comments in your examples, you were prepending your phone number with a 1 - you are not doing that in your php script.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the original question. The problem the whole time is the failure to send the message. I should have worded it better. The redirect is working fine. You are welcome to try it that's why I put the link to my website in the question. The problem is that the script is not actually sending the SMS like it is supposed to. I just get the send message failed.

Comment: The redirect has been working. AS you can see I used a META refresh to do it which will be changed to a Php redirect after I get the text messages to send.

Comment: Ok. 
1) Tell us the exact response you receive from the API.... there are many possible errors that you could be receiving.

2) You are only prepending the mobile number with a 1 in your meta example, and  not in your script example. If you are specifying your number without a country code, it will fail.
3) It would be a good idea to add urlencode() to your username and password to the top of the script.
4) Perhaps error_log() the final URL being used by the script - lets work with that URL. 
5) Would you like easier/simpler sample code?